# Issue having ReturnType inferred in a config parameter of a function

Tags: typescript, parameters, type-inference, return-type

I've simplified my use case to this playground:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQUTLKATwGE4BbABwTXwGVCBnbMgHgFgAoRbxUsYGAHNEaAB7YwAEwaIA3px6LEAbXpM0ZAHIYyaRDCRrm23QwC6ALjkKlt1JmylK1fFYAUASkQBeAHyIAJTQIOBRJFiYUA0EAGkQMMEJfAG4bW0UUcHc09LtyKjAaKCsgqBAUMAAVQgo0Fj4BQVVGYx00M2UAcnssNCcCos6zXxic3K8-RAA3OBhJVK50gF8cpdHF7iMNEzQZMQlpRDcAazRCOGBeBEavADJESOj13zcQ-iErBqEveQ3EAHp-rx0L1EHgCIQrs5CvhEFsyJwVhxOJwethwTAiP0XFB4W5fooGC0NABBKwE9Jovr5HHuCb+fGIURWAAMcUIrMQSw861ymTA2T+uUBiAA6gALSEwBhgTpQRBQcXS-T8NAodCSeIyWRMqxgEBkABGauSiA5iH1RrVXMQAH4xukRQBJJDADDQOIwS5O5DihKCPSK5VQOAWB22EUhaFFcm6h5QKJgQSm82PJOmpG5RQixV6KMUGAAG2tipQcAA7jIEiJ1aE4saIBgQAw9JjEABpTQAeVFtHDShzfvl+ZxD3FcBAhc1xrkcctxpQKb1BoXGf72aBDDgiHLkuQCTl+nlBmA1sx9qFlJpMKgvKz3BFAFVIORdLCQwqUBz1zxI9eY7OzLxomyZmlYaagWs-b0tYl7cFBfxItyCxAA)

And here is the same code:

```js
function createEntityComponentSystem<
    Config extends {
        [SystemName in SystemNames]: {
            createComponent: () => Record<string, any>;
            run: (
                component: ReturnType<Config[SystemName]['createComponent']>,
            ) => void;
        }
    },
    SystemNames extends (keyof Config) & string,
>(config: Config) {
    // Create Entity Component System
}


createEntityComponentSystem({
    systemA: {
        createComponent: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
        run: (
            // Why isn't this inferred as { x: number; y: number } ?
            // In fact, if I change this to:
            // component: { x: string; y: string; }
            // the compiler throws an error, because it KNOWS
            // that component should be { x: number; y: number; }
            // so why can't it infer it?
            component,
            // Uncomment to try:
            // component: { x: string; y: string; },
        ) => {
        },
    }
});
```

If you're wondering why this exists in a record of `SystemName` of `SystemNames`, it's because it's for an Entity Component System. The systems are provided as a single config object, because I'm able to actual validate many type constraints between them when done this way. This is the single outlying issue I'm encountering, as inference has otherwise worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately cannot give details as to why your solution does not work--although the main issue seems to be referring to `Config` inside of `Config`. Either way, here's how you can make it infer...

---

Let's assume we had the type

```
type Config = {
  systemA: {
      x: number;
      y: number;
  };
}
```

We can write a type `Converter<T>` such that `Convert<Config>` outputs the type you want for the function (object with `createComponent` and `run` typings):

```
type Converter<Cfg> = {
  [SystemName in keyof Cfg]: Component<Cfg[SystemName]>
}

interface Component<R> {
  createComponent: () => R;
  run: (component: R) => void;
}
```

If we run `Converter<Config>`, We're taking each key of our `Config` type and doing something like:

```
Component<Config['systemA']>
// Which is the same as
Component<{ x: number; y: number }>
// which is the same as
{
  createComponent: () => { x: number; y: number; };
  run: (component: { x: number; y: number; }) => void;
}
```

Now, we don't want to have to manually define this `Config` type above, but that's ok! We can actually have TypeScript infer this type instead:

```
function createEntityComponentSystem<Config>(
  config: Converter<Config>
) {}
```

And this will work! In your example in the original problem, it will infer `Config` to be:

```
{
  systemA: {
      x: number;
      y: number;
  };
}
```

and, therefore, be able to correctly identify the type of the `component` parameter.

---

The trick here is not having TypeScript directly infer what you want, but infer an intermediate type, which you then convert to your more complex type.